# A generalisation of the equation $n = ab + ac + bc$

Tags: nt.number-theory

In a result I am currently studying (completely unrelated to number theory), I had to examine the solvability of the equation $n = ab+ac+bc$ where $n,a,b,c$ are positive integers $0 < a < b < c.$

As it turned [out](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6388/prime-numbers-p-not-of-the-form-ab-bc-ac-0-a-b-c-and-related-questi) the set of numbers not expressible in the above way is finite.

Generalizing the equation to four variables and checking the solutions of the equation $n = abc+abd+acd+bcd$ for $0 < a < b < c < d$ I've noticed that it looks like there exists a number $n_0$ such that for $n > n_0$ $n$ is expressible as $abc+abd+acd+bcd.$ The fact that a similar pattern occurs for five variables motivates me to ask the following question:

**Question.**  Given a positive integer $m$ is there a number $n_0$ such that every $n > n_0$ is expressible as $$n = x_1\cdots x_m\left(\frac{1}{x_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x_m}\right)$$ where $0 < x_1 < x_2 <\ldots < x_m$.

The question is way too much for my (non-existent) knowledge of number theory. Perhaps there is a known result regarding such equations or, it can be somehow inductively derived from the case $m = 3.$ Any pointers in this direction are appreciated!

Comment: To make this a true generalization, do you want to require $0<x_1<x_2< ...< x_m$?

Comment: I think it is OK to omit the inequality as long as the numbers are taken from a set.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry.

Comment: I would write this as asking for a representation with all positive $x_j$ as 
$$ n = x_1 x_2 \ldots x_m \left( \frac{1}{x_1} +  \frac{1}{x_2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{x_m}     \right) $$
for any $ n > n_0.$ This agrees with your examples for $m=3$ and $m=4.$ Is this what you want? I find your way of writing this and speaking of a set $X$ as clouding the issue.

Comment: If we allow equality, the $n_0$ have been conjectured in http://oeis.org/classic/A027565, which appears to be growing exponentially.

Comment: Why don't you mention the case $m=2$? It's (almost) the abc conjecture! ;-)

Comment: It looks like the special case $m=3$ has roots to the Erdős–Straus conjecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture) and the related one due to Wacław Sierpiński. The wikipedia article at least contains many useful links on this case but also on $m>3$ (including Erdős's paper in Hungarian!).

Comment: By "taken from a set", what you mean is that they're distinct, right?  "Taken from a set" doesn't really mean anything.  But it probably is not worth worrying about distinctness at first...

Comment: This looks like a very difficult problem as the number of variables $m$ is almost the same as the degree $m-1$. It is of similar flavor to the question "Can we write every sufficiently large number as a sum of four cubes?" or "Is $G(k)<100k$ in the Waring problem?" I would be surprised if this problem were resolved in the next 20 years.

Comment: On GH's note, I do not see how to take advantage of homogeneity. So this example may not have the correct taste, then, but $ x^2 + y^2 + z^9 \neq 216 p^3$ for integers $x,y,z$ and any (positive) prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$ The point is that the number of integer triples $(x,y,z)$ such that  $x,y,z \geq 0, \; x^2 + y^2 + z^9 \leq N$ for some large positive $N$ is roughly $C N^{10/9}$ for a constant $C.$ So one might think large values of $N$ would be represented.

Comment: @Will: I am not sure if I am following you, but the heuristic is that if there are no local obstructions (unlike in your example) and the number of variables is sufficiently large (more precisely the sum of reciprocals of the various degrees is large) then there are no global obstructions (i.e. the equation has a solution). There are ambitious conjectures along these lines like $G(k)\ll k$ in the Waring problem, but we are far from proving these.

Comment: GH, I must agree, I was just illustrating that the rough density argument may not be enough. I remember, though, R.C. Vaughan telling Kaplansky that the obstruction here could not be detected $p$-adically, and as such this defeated a conjecture in the first edition of his book on the Hardy-Littlewood method. So, in the second edition, on page 127 it says "There are some exceptions to this, see Exercise 5," then Exercise 5 on page 146 is about $x^2 + y^2 + z^9.$

Comment: @Will: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: GH, good. So my impression of usage is that the factorization trick involved in showing $x^2 + y^2 + z^9 \neq 216 p^3$ is not usually referred to as a local obstruction. Something similar happens with $x^2 + 27 y^2 + 7 z^3,$ another one by Kap with an even larger sum-of-exponent-reciprocals, but having coefficients this time. I sent a variant of that one to the M.A.A. Problems and Solutions, it appeared in December 2010 Monthly. The same trick gives most, or all, easy examples of spinor exceptional integers for positive ternary integral quadratic forms, but not the splitting integers. 

Comment: Numbers of the form $abc + abd + acd + bcd$, with $0 < a < b < c < d$ tabulated at http://oeis.org/A179796 with the observation, "All numbers greater than $181799$ appear to be in this sequence." That page also links back to this question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872324/diophantine-equation-abc-abd-acd-bcd-1/876964#876964

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419766/number-of-solution-for-xy-yz-zx-n/713998#713998

Answer (score -1):

Assume the equation
$$
n=x_1x_2\ldots x_N\left(\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x_N}\right),\tag 1
$$
where $x_i\in\textbf{N}$, $i=1,2,\ldots,N$

I will find the number of solutions of (1) and I will show that exist infinite sequence of natural numbers $n$, such that (1) have always solution.

Write
$$
x_1 x_2\ldots x_N=t,\tag 2
$$
then
$$
n=\frac{t}{x_1}+\frac{t}{x_2}+\ldots+\frac{t}{x_N}.\tag 3
$$
Given $n,t\in\textbf{N}$, the number of solutions of (3) under (2) is
$$
r_0(n,t)=\sum_{\begin{array}{cc}
d_1|t\textrm{, }d_2|t\textrm{, } \ldots\textrm{ , }d_N|t\\
\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{d_N}=\frac{n}{t}\\
d_1d_2 \ldots d_N=t
\end{array}}1.
$$
Since the sum is a divisor sum we can rewrite it as
$$
r_0(n,t)=\sum_{\begin{array}{cc}
d_1|t\textrm{, }d_2|t\textrm{, } \ldots\textrm{ , }d_N|t\\
d_1+d_2+\ldots+d_N=n\\
d_1d_2 \ldots d_N=t^{N-1}
\end{array}}1.\tag 4
$$
Now if we left $t$ varies in $\textbf{N}$, we get from Cauchy inequality
$$
\frac{d_1+d_2+\ldots +d_N}{N}\geq\sqrt[N]{d_1d_2\ldots d_N}\Leftrightarrow \frac{n}{N}\geq\sqrt[N]{t^{N-1}}\Leftrightarrow t\leq\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^{N/(N-1)}.
$$
Hence the number of solutions of (1) is
$$
r(n)=\sum_{t=1}^{\left[\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^{N/(N-1)}\right]}\left(\sum_{\begin{array}{cc}
d_1|t\textrm{, }d_2|t\textrm{, } \ldots\textrm{ , }d_N|t\\
d_1+d_2+\ldots+d_N=n\\
d_1d_2 \ldots d_N=t^{N-1}
\end{array}}1\right).\tag 5
$$
Now it is clear from (5) that if  happens $d_1=d_2=\ldots=d_{N-1}=t$, then $d_N=1$. But this happens if $n$ is of the form
$$
n_k=(N-1)k+1\textrm{, }k\in\textbf{N}.\tag 6
$$
Hence when $n$ is of the form (6) we have always solution.

Comment: Are you just showing that there are infinitely many integers $n$ that can be represented? That fact is obvious.

Comment: @ThomasBrowning no mostly the representation part formula (5). I know that all integers of the form $n=t^{N-1}+(N-1)t^{N-2}$ are  solutions.