# Maximal class of simple graphs of order $n$ with mutually distinct numbers of spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, co.combinatorics, open-problems

This problem in some ways related to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93656/minimal-graphs-with-a-prescribed-number-of-spanning-trees) post.

> Let $A_n$ be the set of all integers $x$ such that there exist a connected simple graph of order $n$ having precisely $x$ spanning trees. Study the growth rate of $|A_n|.$

The question was raised by J.Sedlacek in his paper entitled: *On the number of spanning trees of finite graphs, Cas. Pro. Pest Mat., Vol. 94 (1969) 217-221.*

Sedlacek was able to show that $|A_n| = \omega(n)$ and remarked that it is not known if $|A_n| = \omega(n^2).$

Following are some observations about $|A_n|.$

1. Clearly $|A_n| \leq n^{n-2}$  and $|A_n| \leq |A_{n+1}|$

   - Playing with prime partitions a bit it is possible to show that

   $$ |A_n| = \omega(\sqrt{n}e^{\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{n/\log{n}}})  $$

   - The following table can be computed using sage+nauty:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
n & |A_n| & \frac{n^{n-2}}{|A_n|}\\\
1 & 1 & 1 \\\
2 & 1 & 1 \\\
3 & 2 & 1.5 \\\
4    &   5      &         3.2 \\\
5  &     16      &        7.8  \\\
6   &    65      &        19.9\\\
7  &     386      &       43.5\\\
8   &    3700     &       70.8   \\\ 
9  &     55784    &       85.7\\\
10  &    1134526   &      88.1 \\\
11 &  27053464 &          87.1 \\\
12 & 739026332 &          83.7 \\\
\end{array}
$$

The bound mentioned under 2. was obtained using a construction of graphs with cut vertices. Since almost all graphs are blocks it is (in a way) reasonable to ask

> **Question.** Is there a construction (using blocks)
>   that can improve bound 2.?

I believe that this should also be provable:

> **Conjecture.** $|A_n| = \omega(k^n)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}.$

In case this turns out to be a hard problem I would at least like to extend table 3. further. I am currently computing $|A_n|$ by generating all connected graphs of order $n$ with at least $n$ edges, computing their spanning trees and count distinct such numbers. One optimization could be derived by using the fact that $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ but this is just a minor thing. I therefore leave the following question for the end:

> **Question.** How can we compute $|A_n|$ quickly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to your asymptotics question, but I do have an idea how to approach your problem.  Consider a graph $\Gamma=\Gamma(G_1,\ldots,G_k,H)$, where $H$ is a simple graph on $k$ vertices, where $\Gamma$ is obtained by making $G_i$ to be "parts" and connecting every vertex in $G_i$ with every vertex in $G_j$ if $(i,j)\in H$. This construction generalizes a multipartite graphs and hopefully should give you a better asymptotics if you set up the induction right.

Define $F_G(z) = \sum_r f(G,r) z^r$, where $f(G,r)$ is the number of rooted spanning forests in $G$ with $r$ roots.  This way $F_G(0)$ is $n$ times the number of spanning trees in $G$, and $F_G(1)$ is the number of spanning trees in $\widehat G$, defined as a vertex connected to all $v\in G$.  Turns out, $F_\Gamma$ is a product of $F_{G_i}$ and $F_H$ with appropriate substitutions.  See [this](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/PP-trees-journal.pdf) really short note, and [this preprint](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/KPP-volume.ps) which explains it better.

Comment: @IgorPak Thank you for your answer. The stuff you mention is quite interesting. I am quite slow and can't really grasp the gist of the supplied preprint - the expression for calculating $F_G$ looks a bit messy to me. Could you perhaps extend your answer and supply some more details, perhaps an example? Thank you.