# Create a graph with a specified number of spanning trees

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, laplacian, spanning-tree

I read that one of the current challenging problems in mathematics is [constructing a minimal graph with a specified number of spanning trees](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93656/minimal-graphs-with-a-prescribed-number-of-spanning-trees) (say, $k$).

- However, is there a quick way to create some graph $G$ (*not* necessarily minimal) that has $k$ spanning trees ?

We can compute the number of spanning trees of a graph $G$ using the pseudo-determinant of the Laplacian matrix of $G$ and the number of labelled vertices ([Kirchoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem)).

Perhaps answering the following question helps in answering the original question:

- is there a way to generate a Laplacian matrix given its pseudo-determinant value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A $k$-cycle works if $k>2$.  For $k=1$ any tree works.  I don't think $k=2$ is possible unless you allow double edges: if the graph is not a tree then it has an $m$-cycle $C$ for some $m>2$; remove edges off $C$ until the graph is connected but has no cycle other than $C$, and then removing an arbitrary edge of $C$ yields at least $m$ spanning trees.

Answer (score 7):

If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are graphs let $G_1 \vee G_2$ denote their wedge sum. That is, $G_1 \vee G_2$ is obtained by taking the one-point union of $G_1$ and $G_2$. It will not matter what vertices we decide to identify. If $G_1$ and $G_2$ have $k_1$ and $k_2$ spanning trees respectively, then $G_1 \vee G_2$ has $k_1k_2$ spanning trees.

As Noam points out a $k$-cycle has $k$ spanning trees for $k \geq 3$. So, we have a graph with $k$ spanning trees on $k$ vertices. When $k$ is composite (with some caveats for the prime $2$) we can quickly do better using the above construction. For example, if we want $k = 9$ we take $K_3 \vee K_3$ which has $5$ vertices instead of $9$.

Comment: $k \geq 3$, actually.  Also, the proposer explicitly said they don't care about making the graph small, but it's still nice to know this $G_1 \vee G_2$ construction.  Note, though, that it doesn't work if one of the factors must be $2$, i.e. for $k$ twice a prime or $k=8$.

Comment: @Noam Thanks. Corrections made. Of course it should be $k \geq 3$ (especially since $k=3$ was used in my example). I figured the OP (and possibly others) might be interested in smaller graphs because of the linked question.