# A diophantine equation in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

While I was working on a paper on graph theory, I encountered a problem which I think is a number-theory-problem. I don't know if there are any tools to answer the question.

Find all natural numbers $n$, or prove there are infinitely many $n$, such that the equation $ab+bc+ca=n$ has *no* answer in $\mathbb{N}$.

Can help me or introduce some tools to answer this question?

Thanks

Comment: Setting $a = 0$ we always get a solution (if this is allowed). If not, setting $a = 1$ it is not that hard to see how to get a solution whenever $n+1$ is not prime. I don't know if there is a way to find solutions for $n+1$ prime yet... (edit: For clarity: If $a = 1$, we have $n+1 = (b+1)(c+1)$, this has always a solution if $n+1$ is not prime).

Comment: http://oeis.org/A025052 (the remark "probably the list is complete" means that your question "probably" will not be settled here).

Comment: Related discussions at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6388/prime-numbers-p-not-of-the-form-ab-bc-ac-0-a-b-c-and-related and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33411/a-generalisation-of-the-equation-n-ab-ac-bc

Comment: Actually, the OEIS entry comments that *According to Borwein and Choi, if the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis is true, then this sequence has no larger terms, otherwise there may be one term greater than $10^{11}$*. So, while there is uncertainty about the full list, there are definitely only finitely many.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an elaboration of Emil Jeřábek's important comment, and contains no original contribution. The OP's problem was examined in depth by Borwein-Choi (1999), and their article is available for free [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1046889597). I will summarize the content of this article below.

Let us consider an integer $n\geq 2$ that cannot be written as $ab+bc+ca$ with integers $a,b,c\geq 1$. Using Lemma 1.1 with $k=1$, we see that $n$ is even. Using Theorem 2.6, it follows that either $n\in\{4,18\}$ or $n=2p_1\dots p_r$ with distinct odd primes $p_j$. The proof of these two results are elementary but highly nontrivial. Then, using some results of Andrews and Crandall, the authors deduce that the class number $h(-4n)$ equals $2^r$ (which is the number of genera of discriminant $-4n$). It is classical that $h(-4n)$ is of size $n^{1/2+o(1)}$ while $2^r=n^{o(1)}$, hence the list of exceptional $n$'s is certainly finite. In fact, Weinberger (1973) analyzed the condition $h(-4n)=2^r$ carefully, and this way we know that either $$n\in\{2,4,6,10,18,22,30,42,58,70,78,102,130,190,210,330,462\},$$ or $n$ is possibly 
a further single number beyond $10^{11}$. The last possibility can only occur if the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis (GRH) fails for the $L$-function of some quadratic Dirichlet character.

To summarize, there are $18$ exceptional integers $n\geq 1$ if GRH holds, and possibly one further exceptional $n\geq 1$ if GRH fails. (In the above paragraph I restricted to $n\geq 2$ for convenience.)